# Create list with one key of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this should be an easy one, but because I am not so familiar with python, I haven't quite figured out how it works.
I have the following csv file

```
name        ; type
apple       ; fruit
pear        ; fruit
cucumber    ; vegetable
cherry      ; fruit
green beans ; vegetable
```

What I want to achieve is to list all distinct types with its corresponding name such as:

```
fruit: apple, pear, cherry
vegetable: cucumber, green beans
```

Reading it in with csv.DictReader I can generate a list of dictionaries of that csv File, saved in the variable alldata.

```
alldata = 
[
  {'name':'apple', 'type':'fruit'},
  {'name':'pear',  'type':'fruit'},
  ...
]
```

Now I need a list of all distinct type values from alldata

```
types = ??? #it should contain [fruit, vegetable]
```

such that I can iterate over the list and extract my names corresponding to these types:

```
foreach type in types
  list_of_names = ??? #extract all values of alldata["type"]==type and put them in a new list
  print type + ': ' + list_of_names
```

Does anybody know, how to achieve this?

Comment: `set(row["type"] for row in alldata)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More general approach is to use itertools.groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

food = [
    {'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit'}, 
    {'name': 'pear', 'type': 'fruit'}, 
    {'name': 'parrot', 'type': 'vegetable'}]

for group, items in groupby(sorted(food, key=lambda x: x['type']), lambda x: x['type']):
    print group, list(items) # here is group and items' objects in the group
```

result is:

```
fruit [{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple'}, {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'pear'}]
vegetable [{'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'parrot'}]
```

**UPD**: sort dict before groupby. Thanks @mgilson for point!

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged. **Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.**

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: For what it's worth, this _won't_ work unless the food is pre-sorted by type.

Answer (score 5):

You can use list comprehension to solve this problem :

```
types = set([data['type'] for data in  alldata])

list_of_name = [data['name'] for data in alldata if data['type']==type]
```

Comment: FWIW, `set(data['type'] for data in alldata)` does the same thing without creating an intermediate list :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) structure:

```
types = set((d['type'] for d in alldata))
```

Comment: I accepted Gabz answer, because it also provides the info on how to construct the list of names.

Comment: @kik No problem, it's your call :-)